# How to set threshold while comparing with 4x4 grids

Tags: c, algorithm

I have a question on which the program will allow the iRobot create to move and turn right at 90 degree upon approaching the obstacles.
I am using thermal sensor to capture the temperature difference together with the iRobot Create, the grids will be 4x4.

The idea is that with the aid of 4x4 grids, I will need to do a comparison.

- Read 4x4 grid temperature data from thermal sensor
- Calculate the average temperature of individual row (for R1=j,R2=k,R3=l,R4=m)
- Find the highest average temperature among all the rows
- Divide individual rows by highest average temperature
- Let X=(R1+R2)/2 and Y=(R3+R4)/2
- Compare X and Y,condition: if X is less than Y=0.08, it will move forward. If it is more than 0.08, it will turn away

-

```
void detection(void) 
{
    int j,k,l,m,a,b,c,d,x,y

    %average values for each row (RowAverage)

    readbuff[i] = recv_data;
    j=(readbuff[2]+readbuff[3]+readbuff[4]+readbuff[5]+readbuff[6]+readbuff[7]+readbuff[8]+readbuff[9])/4
    k= (readbuff[10]+readbuff[11]+readbuff[12]+readbuff[13]+readbuff[14]+readbuff[15]+readbuff[16]+readbuff[17])/4
    l= (readbuff[18]+readbuff[19]+readbuff[20]+readbuff[21]+readbuff[22]+readbuff[23]+readbuff[24]+readbuff[25])/4
    m= (readbuff[26]+readbuff[27]+readbuff[28]+readbuff[29]+readbuff[30]+readbuff[31]+readbuff[32]+readbuff[33])/4`

    %find the highest average among the 4 rows (HighestAverage)

    if (j > k)
    {
        a=j;
    }
    else (a>k)
    {
        a=k;
    }

    if (k > l)
    {
        a=k;
    }
    else (a>l)
    {
        a=l;
    }

    if (l > m)
    {
        a=l;
    }
    else (a>m)
    {
        a=m;
    }

    %divide individual row
    b=j/a
    c=k/a
    d=l/a
    e=m/a

    %average of the top 2 rows and bottom 2 rows
    x=(j+k)/2
    y=(l+m)/2
    ...
}
```

May I know how to set threshold so that when x is less than y, itdoes not go beyond 0.08?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to make sure that when x is less than y, that the value of x is never more than 0.08 you can do the following:

```
if (x < y) {        
    if (x > 0.08) {
           x = 0.08;
    }
}
```

Comment: Let's say if i were to add in actions like move forward or turn away, I will follow your answer and straight away continue to add on? I will need to declare a function for "moveforward" and "turnaway"? I am not really sure about the codes for the features.